# How to handle a circular reference when it is a single property?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm in a Spring project where I find myself with a circular reference problem that's a bit different from the ones already posted here (at least the ones I managed to find).

### Class structure

The application has a user class/entity. This entity can send "ducks" to other users. It has an aggregation relationship (a list) with the users who have been sent a "duck", and another list with the users who have sent you one. (It is an M-N cardinality relationship)

```
@Entity
public class User{
    @ManyToMany
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JoinTable(
        name = "sendsDuck",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sender"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "receiver")
    )
    private Set<User> duckedUsers;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "duckedUsers")
    @JsonBackReference
    private set <User> receivesDuckFrom;
    
    //Getters and setters
    ...

}
```

As you can see I have added the `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` tags to precisely avoid self-reference or cyclic reference.

### Problem

The problem is, when one user sends a "duck" to another, the tags I mentioned above fixed the circular referencing problem. However, when two users send sensitive ducks to each other (A sends to B and B sends to A) I have a circular reference that I don't know how to handle.

This is because both objects have the other within the same `duckedUsers` property.

### What have I tried so far?

This is a list of the attempts I have made so far but haven't worked:

- @JsonIgnore

This annotation works fine if I put it on the `duckedUsers` property. However, the API client needs to know the data of the users to whom it sent a duck, so this solution is not sufficient for my case.

- @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference on the same property

Bit of a silly attempt, but try using both annotations on the same property, even though they didn't make much sense. Also without success.

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JoinTable(
            name = "sendsDuck",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sender"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "receiver")
    )
```

- Object Mapper

Inside the controller, try using an objectMapper configured in the following ways:

```
ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SELF_REFERENCES_AS_NULL, true);
```

```
ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_SELF_REFERENCES, false);
```

And using it like this:

```
    @PostMapping("/sendDuck")
    ResponseEntity sendDuck(@RequestParam Long transmitterId, @RequestParam Long receiverId) {
        User transmitter = this.findOrThrow(transmitterId);
        User receiver = this.findOrThrow(receiverId);
        transmitter.sendsDuck(receiver);
        repository.save(transmitter);
        repository.save(receiver);
        List<User> usersList = List.of(receiver, transmitter);
        CollectionModel<EntityModel<User>> body = this.collectionModelFromList(usersList);
        try{
            String serializedBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(body);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(body);
        }catch (IOException ex){
            String errorMessage = "JSON serializing error: " + ex.getMessage();
            return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().body(errorMessage);
        }
    }
```

This attempt was also unsuccessful.

### How do I think the solution should look like?

From what I've seen so far, I understand that what I'm looking to achieve would be a JSON response that works in a way that the `@JsonIgnore` is applied only if the entity is a child in the response. Something like that:

```
{
   id:1,
   ...
   duckedUsers:[
      {
         id:1,
         ... 
         duckedUsers:... //This must NOT appear as is a child entity
      },
   ]
}
```

Comment: Stepping back a moment: when you have this type of many-to-many relationship, sometimes the best thing to do is to create a junction relationship between the two (DB terms). In other words, rather than each `User` having a list of other `User`s involved in ducking each other [sic.], you can instead have a list of "duckings" that happened (e.g. a `List<Pair<User, User>>`, where the first user "ducked" the second). This provides a decoupling of the User from the action you are trying to track here, and they can be loaded or queried separately.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll implement it nad upload the code. Thank you

Comment: See @JsonIdentityInfo which is closer to what you want- it will trim repeats in a graph so that only the ID is included. See https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rogue has explained in the comments, the better solution was decoupling the User entity and the Ducks relations. This is how the code has ended:

User entity

```
@Entity
public class User{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sender")
    private Set<Duck> ducksSent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver")
    private Set<Duck> ducksReceived;

    //Constructor, getters and setters....
}
```

Duck entity

```
@Entity
public class Duck {
   
    @EmbeddedId
    private DuckId id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("senderId")
    private User sender;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("receiverId")
    private User receiver;


    public Duck(User sender, User receiver) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.id = new DuckId(sender.getId(),receiver.getId());
    }

    //getters and setters....
}
```

Comment: How though does this resolve your issue? User A and B still can ‘duck’ each other concurrently same as before. Only change is you now have access to state in the relationship (there isn’t any, but could be later). Querying options are similar as well. Json with this as is will have circular references- a stackoverflow exception

Comment: No, because the property duckedUsers and receivedDuckFrom are not in the User class anymore. So, there is no circular reference.